# How can I use a Teensy for a CAN bus project?

Tags: can, teensy

I have to use CAN Bus in my project. I need to use the Arduino software and a Teensy but I don't know what parts I should buy or how to make it work.

I have chosen Teensy 3.2 With CAN-Bus Breakout Board:

[CAN Bus Breakout](https://copperhilltech.com/teensy-3-6-dual-can-bus-breakout-board-with-oled-display/)

Does this product includes CAN Bus?

I don't know what list of parts I have to buy to make it work.

Do I connect Teensy via usb to pc and that's it? Or do I have to connect the Teensy to a CAN Bus?

Comment: CAN bus is just a communications / interface standard. What is the actual goal of the project? That breakout board will allow you to interface to a CAN bus, but what do you require the CAN bus for?

Comment: I have to use CAN Bus with power supply in project, but I don't have power supply now and meanwhile I just want to talk to CAN Bus. To learn how to communicate with him. Send him and receive messages. I don't have background in this field, because of that I need to know what steps should I make to communicate with him.

Comment: "I have to use CAN Bus with power supply in project" - What is this project? If you don't have a power supply you're not going to be able to get the CAN bus working. You can communicate to the BUS you need devices on the BUS to communicate with. Perhaps read a CAN spec first - http://www.ti.com/lit/an/sloa101b/sloa101b.pdf

Comment: I don't have the actual instrument (power supply) here for the moment, I want to simulate using can bus before I will get it. What kind of device can I use for demo purpose?

Comment: Well you could use a second Teensy + shield and test Teensy to Teensy CAN bus

Comment: Thank you.
So what i need to buy is 2 Teensy. I don't need to buy CAN bus ?(because it's built in Teensy 3.2 With CAN-Bus Breakout Board).

Comment: You will require two of the can-bus breakout boards as well. The CAN bus is an electrical communications standard so you cant buy 'a CAN bus'. What you are buying is the CAN bus breakout which converts serial data from the Arduino to the correct voltages and timings to comply with the CAN bus specification. I hope that makes sense

Comment: You said "as well" and "What you are buying is the CAN bus breakout ".
Is it enough to buy 2 of these?: https://copperhilltech.com/teensy-3-6-dual-can-bus-breakout-board-with-oled-display/
or should i buy 2 more of something else?
And should i buy two of these like on video. two white platforms with many holes? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yQpfbf48dPQ

Comment: The answer to what you need entirely depends on what you're trying to achieve. Those white platforms are breadboards used for electronics prototyping. They would be useful but again it depends on your project. Is this for a university course by any chance?

Comment: No, it's for work. This demo project that I want to test has no relation to actual project, I just want to learn how to send and receive messages via CAN bus protocol. I buy teensy just for demo. If i buy 2 of this teensy dual breakout board, is it will be enough to make conversation between them via CAN bus protocol? Or i should in addition to buy other things?

Comment: Yes you will need 2xTeensy and 2xBreakout board. You should then be able to wire the two breakout boards together to create a CAN bus between the two teensys

Comment: I just don't understand why they call it "Teensy 3.6 Dual CAN Bus Breakout Board With OLED Display". Is it a Teensy or Breakout board or 2 in 1 ?

Comment: Reading the description is does include the teensy "This is a dual channel CAN Bus breakout board for use with the Teensy 3.6, which is included. So yes it does come with the teensy

Comment: So if you buy two of those kits that would give you 2xteensy and 2xbreakout which should be all you need (aside from some wire!)

Comment: Ill add what we've discussed as an answer, Id be grateful if you could accept it

Comment: accepted the answer

Comment: This seems to be *exactly* the same situation ("*I have to use CAN Bus with power supply in project, but I don't have power supply now*") as this question from a few days ago: "[CAN Bus first steps](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/419616/101852)" ("*I will need to build a project that will let me connect from my PC to a power supply via CAN bus. I don't have this power supply here*") and *exactly* the same Teensy CAN breakout board was mentioned in an answer there. Therefore despite the different user accounts used to ask the questions, there seems to be some link...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could buy 2 lots of the shield you mention [here](https://copperhilltech.com/teensy-3-6-dual-can-bus-breakout-board-with-oled-display/)

As these come with a Teensy you would have 2x Teensy and 2x Breakout

This would allow you to make a CAN bus between the 2 Teensys and test your software